# Using unique_ptr in FreeRTOS

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to implement smart pointers for our project.
We're using FreeRTOS which is written with a C API so it was quite a challenge to implement sending smart pointers around but somehow I managed it by combining casts, new calls (dont really like that..) move semantics and some other tricks.

On the surface it behaves as expected, but I want to be sure there is not any memory leak.
Furthermore, is there a way to use make_unique together with new? I have not really found a way yet.

Here is the code, it should work with an online C++ compiler (or use this [link](http://cpp.sh/9ihry)). It would be great if an expert could look over this. Maybe some things can be optimized, or maybe this code is not save at all and I just dont see it.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>

class DummyHelper {
public:
    DummyHelper(uint8_t someResource): someResource(someResource) {}

    virtual ~DummyHelper() {
       someResource = 0;
       std::cout << "Dtor called" << std::endl;
    }

    int getResource() {
       return someResource;
    }
private:
   int someResource = 0; 
};

class CommandMessage {
public:
    CommandMessage() = default;
    virtual~ CommandMessage() {};

    void setParameter(uint64_t parameter) {
        memcpy(rawContent.data() + 4, &parameter, sizeof(parameter));
    }

    uint64_t getParameter() const {
       uint64_t param;
       memcpy(&param, rawContent.data() + 4, sizeof(param));
       return param;
    }

private:
    std::array<uint8_t, 12> rawContent;
};

void setTestMessage(CommandMessage *testMsg,
       uint8_t someResource) {
  auto unique_pptr = new std::unique_ptr<DummyHelper>(new DummyHelper(someResource));
  uint64_t test_ptr = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(unique_pptr);
  testMsg->setParameter(test_ptr);
}

std::unique_ptr<DummyHelper> getUniquePtr(
       CommandMessage *testMsg) {
   uint64_t raw_ptr = testMsg->getParameter();
   auto unique_pptr = reinterpret_cast<std::unique_ptr<DummyHelper>*>(raw_ptr);
   auto unique_ptr = std::move(*unique_pptr);
   delete unique_pptr;
   return unique_ptr;
}


int main()
{
  auto storagePtr = std::make_unique<DummyHelper>(42);
  CommandMessage testMessage;
  std::cout << "Setting message" << std::endl;
  setTestMessage(&testMessage, 42);
  // a message has been set and can be sent, e.g. via a message queue

  // in another class, the pointer is retrieved.
  auto unique_ptr = getUniquePtr(&testMessage);
  DummyHelper & test = *unique_ptr;
  std::cout << test.getResource() << std::endl;
  unique_ptr.reset();
}
```

Comment: Yes it leaks. SImply count the calls to new/delete and make sure they are the same. They are not. But I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Why are you trying to create a smart pointer when you are using a smart pointer! You have a `std::unique_ptr` this is a smart pointer.

Comment: I think I am not able to send it via the message queue. If i create a simple unique_ptr and copy it into the message queue, the resource will be destroyed  after going out of scope. I don't think it is possible to transfer ownership to the FreeRTOS message queue, given it was not programmed with C++ features in mind. I actually updated the code: I deleted the pointer in the getUniquePtr() call.

Comment: You're making a pointer. To a unique_ptr. With new. I don't think you grasp the concept of smart pointers yet.

Answer (score 3):

3 years late to the party, but here's my suggestion to solve the problem.  I'm assuming you specifically want to send a smart pointer through the FreeRTOS Queue.  Your implementation technically works, but has a couple of issues:

1. You are sending 'unique_pptr' to the receiver which is a non-smart pointer.  That defeats your original purpose.  Your 'unique_pptr' can potentially leak.
2. The sending thread and receiving thread both have access to the same instance of std::unique_ptr.   However, std:unique_ptr is not thread safe.

Reference counting using a C API can't be done effectively, so it's not worth trying.  Instead make the C++ std::queue thread-safe and synchronized using FreeRTOS.

I'm using the CMSIS wrapper for FreeRTOS, but it's easily translated.

```
#pragma once
#include <queue>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>
#include "cmsis_os.h"

template <typename T>
class MessageQueue
{
public:
    MessageQueue()
    {
        mSemaId = osSemaphoreNew(std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max(), 0, nullptr);
        mMutexId = osMutexNew(nullptr);
        
    };

    ~MessageQueue()
    {
        if (mSemaId)
        {
            osSemaphoreDelete(mSemaId);
        }
        
        if (mMutexId)
        {
            osMutexDelete(mMutexId);
        }
    };
    
    void PushBack(const T& value)
    {
        // add an item to the queue, but thread safely
        osMutexAcquire(mMutexId, osWaitForever);
        mQueue.push(value);
        osMutexRelease(mMutexId);

        osSemaphoreRelease(mSemaId);  // signal another message is ready

    }
    
    
    T PopFront()
    {
        // wait here for a message to come in
        osSemaphoreAcquire(mSemaId, osWaitForever);  // use a timeout parameter instead
        
        // take the first item out of the queue, but thread safely
        osMutexAcquire(mMutexId, osWaitForever);
        T value = mQueue.front();
        mQueue.pop();
        osMutexRelease(mMutexId);

        return value;
    }
    
    
private:
    std::queue<T> mQueue;   // <--- replaces the FreeRTOS queue
    osSemaphoreId_t mSemaId = nullptr;
    osMutexId_t mMutexId = nullptr;
};
```

Basic usage shown, but no thread creation for clarity

```
struct Msg
{
     using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<Msg>;
     std:string data;
};

class ReceiverThread
{
    
public:
    
    void CalledBySenderThread(const Msg::Ptr& msg)
    {
        mMessageQueue.PushBack(msg);
    }

private:   
    void ReceiverThreadLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Msg::Ptr msg = mMessageQueue.PopFront();
            // process(msg);
            // msg is automatically deleted
        }
    }

    MessageQueue<Msg::Ptr> mMessageQueue;
};
```

Notice I'm using std::shared_ptr.  I only want the message destroyed once the sender AND receiver have finished using it.  I could use std::unique_ptr but would require the additional move semantics.

One gotcha: you can't access the queue from an interrupt.

Answer (score 2):

### Overview:

In relation to the message queue:

- Since you are doing a manual `new` and `delete` that seems a bit of a waste.
- Also the only thing you are creating is a unique_ptr.
- The unique_ptr is never in stored correctly typed so it never does any work.

So I would not store a pointer to a `std::unique_ptr` I would just store the original pointer. I like the idea of passing in and retrieving a `unique_ptr` to the access function.

---

Why are you passing a pointer to `CommandMessage`? It can't be null (you never check so must be valid. To make this more formal pass by reference to indicate to the user that it should be a normal object.

```
void setTestMessage(CommandMessage *testMsg, uint8_t someResource)
std::unique_ptr<DummyHelper> getUniquePtr(CommandMessage *testMsg)

// I would do this:

void setTestMessage(CommandMessage& testMsg, uint8_t someResource)
std::unique_ptr<DummyHelper> getUniquePtr(CommandMessage& testMsg)
```

Note: Putting the '*' on the right by the variable is very "C" like. C++ considers this part of the type information so it is usually on the left with the type.

---

Why is the input message different from the output message?

```
void setTestMessage(CommandMessage *testMsg, uint8_t someResource)
std::unique_ptr<DummyHelper> getUniquePtr(CommandMessage *testMsg)
```

So input is a `uint8_t` but the output is `std::unique_ptr<DummyHelper>`? I would expect the interface to be symmetric.

```
template<typename T>
void sendMessage(CommandMessage& messageStream, std::unique_ptr<T>&& msg);

template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> recvMessage(CommandMessage& messageStream);
```

---

```
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> recvMessage(CommandMessage& messageStream)
{
   // To store pointers in an integer type you should be using `std::intptr_t`
   // This is an int type that is guaranteed large enough to store a pointer.
   // Don't make the assumption that `uint64_t` is large enough.
   // It might be but that is not guaranteed for the future.
   std::intptr_t raw_ptr = messageStream.getParameter();

   return reinterpret_cast<T*>(raw_ptr);
}


template<typename T>
void sendMessage(CommandMessage& messageStream, std::unique_ptr<T>&& msg)
{
    messageStream.setParameter(msg.release());
}
```

---